# How to treat $\Delta$t in instantaneous velocity equations?

Tags: calculus, limits

The background to my question is that I'm trying to teach myself Calculus using a variety of resources. So far I've found that most of my confusions as I go along can be resolved simply by jumping between texts, but in the case of this small issue I've found something which seems equally taken for granted in all the resources I've looked at. So, I'm looking for help to get the right intuition.

Take the following equation from a textbook I've been using called Quick Calculus:

[image]

My discomfort is over the last part where

$2kt + k\Delta t$ is simplified to $2kt$.

1. Is it possible to do this simply because the limit is approaching $0$, so we  treat  $\Delta t$ as being effectively $0$?
2. If so, why do we wait until the very last step to make this simplification? We could have done it already by step three.

My guesses are that the answer to my first question is yes, we can effectively treat it as zero here, and if the limit were approaching $1$ we would treat it as $1$, etc; and that to the second question, it must have something to do with avoiding dividing by zero when our equation for $\Delta S$ is put into the $\dfrac{\Delta S}{\Delta t}$ equation.

Even if the answers are as simple as I just put them, I appreciate a response. I haven't been able to find any published resource that explicitly states the thought process behind solving this kind of problem, and I really want to get my own thought-process habits and intuitions solid before moving on to harder problems. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. As far as the properties of limits are concerned, given that the limits at points of functions which are continuous can be computed simply by computing the function at that point, can the same be confidently said of functions which are continuous everywhere except for zero?

Comment: No.  The definition of continuity at a point $a$ is $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = f(a)$.  So if you're trying to evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ where $f$ is not continuous at $0$, then *by definition*, it won't equal $f(0)$ (it'll be something else or might not even exist).  Of course, if that's the only point of discontinuity, then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = f(a)$ would hold for any $a$ *besides* $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically yes.

1. Using the [properties of limits](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LimitsProperties.aspx), $$\begin{align}\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}(2kt+k\Delta t) &= \lim_{\Delta t\to 0}2kt + \lim_{\Delta t\to 0} k\Delta t \\ &= 2kt + \lim_{\Delta t\to 0} k\Delta t &\text{($2kt$ is constant with respect to $\Delta t$)}\\ &= 2kt + k\lim_{\Delta t\to 0} \Delta t &\text{(pulling a constant factor out of the limit)}\\ &= 2kt + k(0) \\ &= 2kt\end{align}$$
2. If you tried to apply these properties before the point where you cancel the $\Delta t$ in the denominator you'd just get $\dfrac 00$, which is undefined.  So you have to do some algebra on the expression before you can evaluate the limit.  This is pretty typical of how to evaluate a derivative from its limit definition.